# Can a Window (of WPF) know whether it is opened by ShowDialog()?

Tags: c#, wpf

Can a `Window(System.Windows)` know whether it is opened by `Show()` or `ShowDialog()`?

If `DialogResult` is set on a window which is opened by `Show()` method,
it throws an `InvalidOperationException`([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.dialogresult(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Is there any way to know how the window is opened and to avoid it?
Should I use `try-catch`?

```
public partial class Window1 : Window {
    public Window1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void CancelButton_OnClick([NotNull] object sender, [NotNull] RoutedEventArgs e) {
        DialogResult = false; // throws an InvalidOperationException.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you John, I didn't think of searching "modal". The question you linked is just what I wanted to know!

Answer (score 1):

`System.Windows.Interop.ComponentDispatcher.IsThreadModal` gets a value if the calling thread is modal, i.e. if it has been opened using `Window.ShowDialog()`

Comment: I am sure that many windows are opened on same thread. Modal is state of exact window handle...

Comment: Thank you @Abishek. I didn't know about `ComponentDispatcher`. I will learn about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a new class based on `Window` with overriden/new `ShowDialog()` method, which sets public property `bool IsModal` to `true` if it is called. Don't forget to call `base.ShowDialog()`. You will probably will have to add some changes to XAML file (class name or etc).

But you should check first if you need to add `IsModal` property on your class instance. Otherwise, or if you want to check this for any other window, this will not help.

Comment: I found that `Window.ShowDialog()` and `Window.Show()` is not `virtual`. And I don't want to use `new`...